# ZSH shell start up profiling

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

my zsh shell has a quite long start up time and if I hold done the enter key the terminal prompt lags behind significantly. So I looked out for solutions and profiling options and found [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5327) github issue. Further done [one comment suggests](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5327#issuecomment-455763912) to run the following commands:

```
zsh -xv 2>&1 | ts -i "%.s" > zsh_startup.log
```

followed by

```
sort --field-separator=' ' -r -k1 zsh_startup.log> sorted.log
```

which gives me the following output:

```
2.106722 ESC[?1hESC=ESC[?1lESC>l
1.388755 ESC[?1hESC=ESC[?1lESC>l
1.185498 ESC[?1hESC=ESC[?1lESC>exit
1.153527 ESC[?1hESC=ESC[?1lESC>ls -la
0.065941 +powerline_precmd:1> PS1=$'%{\C-[[38;5;15m%}%{\C-[[48;5;31m%} ~ %{\C-[[48;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;31m%}%{\C-[[38;5;250m%}%{\C-[[48;5;237m%} Private %{\C-[[48;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;244m%}%{\C-[[38;5;254m%}%{\C-[[48;5;237m%} tmp %{\C-[[48;5;238m%}%{\C-[[38;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;39m%}%{\C-[[48;5;238m%} 1 %{\C-[[48;5;236m%}%{\C-[[38;5;238m%}%{\C-[[38;5;15m%}%{\C-[[48;5;236m%} %# %{\C-[[0m%}%{\C-[[38;5;236m%}%{\C-[[0m%} '
0.052396 +powerline_precmd:1> PS1=$'%{\C-[[38;5;15m%}%{\C-[[48;5;31m%} ~ %{\C-[[48;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;31m%}%{\C-[[38;5;250m%}%{\C-[[48;5;237m%} Private %{\C-[[48;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;244m%}%{\C-[[38;5;254m%}%{\C-[[48;5;237m%} tmp %{\C-[[48;5;238m%}%{\C-[[38;5;237m%}%{\C-[[38;5;39m%}%{\C-[[48;5;238m%} 1 %{\C-[[48;5;236m%}%{\C-[[38;5;238m%}%{\C-[[38;5;15m%}%{\C-[[48;5;236m%} %# %{\C-[[0m%}%{\C-[[38;5;236m%}%{\C-[[0m%} '
...
```

It looks like the first four commands (or whatever the lines represent) are taking up the majority of the time. I'm having a hard time understanding the output and would like to have some guidance in interpreting the first lines - no need for solving the underlying problem of having a slow shell :) just the interpretation of the first four lines.

The file itself is much longer and I just included the first few lines.

Notes:

- I'm using oh-my-zsh with the following plugins

  plugins=(
    z
    git
    kubectl
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
    zsh-autosuggestions
  )
- I configured `l` to be an alias for `l -la` in my `.zshrc`
- this is what happens when I keep pressing the enter key:
  (when there are no gaps between prompts I had already released the enter key again)

[image]